# What is the meaning of this sentence: overthrow the Emperor with him ?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080684/synopsis)

> Luke screams in denial. Vader tries to persuade Luke to join him,
>   embrace the Dark Side of the Force, and **overthrow the Emperor with
>   him.**

My Understanding: Vader belong to emperor & he owns it, then why he want overthrow that?

What is the meaning of this sentence: overthrow the Emperor with him ?

Comment: _Overthrow the Emperor with him_ is a _clause,_ not a _sentence._ It means _Participate with him in the activity of overthrowing the Emperor._ Can you tell us, please, who recommended movie reviews from IMDB.com as texts to use in your study of English?

Comment: Please stop asking these questions on ELL, they do not belong here and are not related to learning the English language. These questions can be easily answered by watching Star Wars movies or searching Google. They do not have anything to do with the usage of the English language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence is complex, and is easier to understand if we break it up.

> Vader tries to persuade Luke to join him.
>
> Vader tries to persuade Luke to embrace the Dark Side of the Force.
>
> Vader tries to persuade Luke to overthrow the Emperor with him.

Both Luke and Vader are trying to overthrow the Emperor, but they have different goals in mind.

Luke is a Rebel who is trying to destroy the Empire and remove it from power.

Darth Vader is a high-ranking member of the Empire who wants to enact a coup, killing the Emperor and then taking control of the Empire for himself.

If Luke were to help Darth Vader overthrow the Emperor, he would be taking Vader's job while Vader becomes the new Emperor.  They would crush the Rebellion and rule the galaxy together.